# How to merge multiple messages from pushnotification as a single message in reactnative firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

We are trying to implement PushNotification service through firebase cloud messaging. We implemented the device group which can send multiple messages to multiple devices. The problem is that each time we are sending a msg to the registered device we are getting a separate notification instead of merged notification messages like WhatsApp.

How can we achieve this functionality?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here am posting my own answer. What we have done is so simple yet effective.
We have used **tag** Attribute which replaces the existing notifications with a new one.